# Where are my deleted answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, recently-deleted

My deleted recent answers link in the profile is showing only the recent 10 deleted answers. Where can I see all my deleted answers? Are they all permanently removed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The deleted answers list only includes posts deleted in the past 60 days.

The rest are not permanently deleted, but you need to know where you posted them, as there currently is no way to list them all (unless you are a diamond moderator or Stack Exchange developer).

If you do remember what question they were posted on, you as the author can still see them by visiting that question, as can anyone with 10k+ reputation.

Comment: This is SUPER lame...I don't know why it's lame exactly, but I KNOW it's lame.  And SE bureaucracy :(

Comment: @lilredindy: this answer is no longer accurate, you can now view all your deleted posts, see [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184)

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

If there was some reputation changes due to that post (or voting was performed on that post), you can go to your reputation tab. Here you can see all your posts where voting was performed (i.e. even if you didn't earn or lose reputation due to any reason). And yes don't forget to tick the option 'show removed posts'. You don't need to 10k privilege here.